# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous while using if conditional statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, any

I have sentinel-2 images and I am calculating the MNDWI(Modified Normalised Difference Water Index) using Green and Short Wave Infrared bands, after calculating the MNDWI, I want to just output the values which are positive i.e., greater than 0 but I am getting this error. Anyone please guide me, Thanks is anticipation.

Here is the code snipet:

```
mndwi = (green.astype(float) - swir1.astype(float)) / (green + swir1)
 for i in range(len(mndwi)): 
   if mndwi[i] > 0:  **{I am getting error here}**
     pass
 print(mndwi)
```

Comment: The value in `mndwi[i]` seems to be a numpy array, you either need to use `all`, `any`, or you want to compare a value instead of the array

Comment: I have use any and all both, in case of any() it gives me both negative and positive values while I just want to print positive values. In case of all(), it does not give any output.

Comment: @ThePyGuy yes the value in mndwi[i] is a numpy array,  and I want to compare the value in the array.

Comment: As it is an array, you need another loop inside the first loop where you'll be iterating the values i. e. `for value in mndwi[i]` then use condition inside this loop and check if `value>0`